# Why is Property execution slower than Field or Method execution?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, synchronization, clr

In [CLR via CSharp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004OR1XV0) chapter 10 "Properties" Jeff Richter writes:

> A property method can take a long time to execute; ﬁeld access always
>   completes  immediately. A common reason to use properties is to
>   perform thread synchroni- zation, which can stop the thread forever,
>   and therefore, a property should not be  used if thread
>   synchronization is required. In that situation, a method is preferred.
>   Also, if your class can be accessed remotely (for example, your class
>   is derived from  System.MarshalByRefObject), calling the property
>   method will be very slow, and  therefore, a method is preferred to a
>   property. In my opinion, classes derived from  MarshalByRefObject
>   should never use properties.

Is this the case even if the property is defined to just return the private field? Why is a *Method* preferred in synchronization? and why is a *Method* preferred in MarshalByRefObject scenario?

To clarify my question:
 Jeff seems to be making a blanket statement that Properties are not advisable, and that methods are preferable in those 2 scenarios. as Joe White pointed out, properties can have arbitrary code. But methods can run the same arbitrary code. That's the part i'm having difficulty with. Is there actually advantage in using methods over properties (given the same code is used) for synchronization or marshaling, or does he merely have a problem with language convention?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think he's making the point that, because a property can run any arbitrary code, the *calling code* shouldn't assume that it will finish immediately.

If all the property does is return a field, then its method body will actually be inlined by the JIT compiler and it'll be just as fast as a field access. So it's not that properties are somehow slower; it's that they're black boxes. If you don't know how a property is implemented, you can't make assumptions about it returning quickly.

(That said, making a slow property would be a clear violation of the [.NET Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054.aspx), specifically this one: "Do use a method, rather than a property, [if the] operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field set would be".)

As for his suggestion of using methods instead, I can't make any sense of that. Properties *are* methods: the property getter is a method (typically named `get_PropertyName`), and the property setter is a method (`set_PropertyName`), and code that reads the property is compiled to code that makes a method call to `get_PropertyName`. There's nothing special that would make a property any slower than a method.

Comment: Jeff's point is that a "GetBlah" method call *communicates to the reader* "this might be slow" and a "Blah" property communicates "this is almost certainly fast". So if you are going to make something slow, make it a method. I don't *entirely* agree with this advice -- for example, I often make properties that have slow *unlikely worst cases* but have excellent *amortized* performance. But Jeff's advice is definitely a good starting point; deviate from it once you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

I think the point is that property access looks like a field access, so people don't expect anything unusual.

If you have a property that can take a long time, you should rewrite it into a method. It won't make your code perform any better, but it will be more clear that it might take a long time.

As far as performance goes, there is no difference between property access and method call. Actually property access *is* just a method call.

Comment: well.. he did explicitly say " calling the property method will be very slow, and therefore, a method is preferred to a property". so it's not just about appearances.. at least according to Jeff..

Comment: Calling the property will be slow, and people don't expect properties to be slow. Calling a method will be equally slow, but people expect that some methods are slow.

Answer (score 3):

A Method is not faster than a property, but a method is not expected to be as fast as a property. So the method is preferred to make clear that it might take some time (because of thread synchronization in this case).

Fields are not "executed" at all. Accessing a field is directly accessing memory.

Comment: Accessing an instance field is *indirectly* accessing memory, because first you have to locate the *receiver* in memory.

Comment: @Eric: yes, sure, I mean that you are accessing memory, not executing code.